# Detect query which is being Posted

Tags: java, http, post

i need to detect the query which is being Post to a server because i want to build a query(the query will be built with java code) and then Post a request to the server.Then i will scrape the html content that user agent returned to my program.The site that i want the returned html content is this ->  https://www.obi.gr/obi/Default.aspx?tabid=125

Does anybody has any idea how could i possible see the query which is being Posted to the server?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can monitor network calls in `chrome` or `firefox` in developers tools

Comment: The request to get a HTML page from a server is almost always a GET request, not POST.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Network` tab on Chrome Developer Tools.

You will get the exact list of calls being made to server from your browser.

Click on a call to see details about it, the request parameters, header, etc being sent with request

[image]

Comment: It does not seem to work.The field query string paramaters does not contain something usesful.The value is ->tabid:125

Comment: then it seems you need to check whether that parameter is being sent from your code.

Comment: That is the problem.I need to detect the query which is posted to the server so i can build a similar one with my code